# The figure shows differently in PDF format with MatPlotLib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

The simple time series data I 'm plotting contains some NaN values. So, when I tried to save the figure content into **pdf** format, the discrete point is disappearing.

Here is an example of my problem. I have uploaded the example files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQUmtrTE1GVHpMRjA).

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16,4))
ax = plt.subplot()
plt.plot(df['date'], df['value'], 'o-') 
plt.savefig("./xxx.pdf")
plt.show()
```

The output should be like the figure below:

[image]

But the pdf file doesn't contain the **point** sample in the middle of the plot.

[image]

If the figure is saving in the format of 'png' or 'jpeg', this wizard phenomenon would be solved.

Due to the small size and high quality of pdf file, I still want to save the figure into pdf format.

Any advices would be appreciated!

Comment: The issue is not reproducible. When running the code with your data, I get **exactly** the same plot that is shown as pdf, including all single dots. [Screenshot from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLznX.png)

Comment: This is a known bug when plotting isolated points in vector graphics formats. See [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7293/). It sounds like its been fixed in v2.0.1. See also [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/8297)